# How to download attachment from OERP using oerplib

Tags: python, odoo

I am working on a project moving data from Open ERP to Xero. I am stuck on moving attachments. I am using a Python lib oerplib 0.8.3. I can't find a way to download an attachment or is there a way to move them directly to Xero from Open ERP.
Using the usual oerplib methods I have managed to get some data on attachments:

```
attachment_obj = oerp.get('ir.attachment')
attachment_ids = attachment_obj.search([])
```

Sample Data:

```
{
    "create_date": "2013-10-09 08:35:07", 
    "file_type": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet", 
    "res_model": "project.task", 
    "write_uid": 4, 
    "res_name": "Map Categories", 
    "db_datas": "False", 
    "file_size": "27278", 
    "partner_id": 44, 
    "id": "111", 
    "create_uid": 4, 
    "user_id": 4, 
    "company_id": 1, 
    "parent_id": "False", 
    "index_content": "", 
    "type": "binary", 
    "store_fname": "5a2/5a264e792eaa5305879a89e7ce2cbb6bd0099fcd", 
    "description": "False", 
    "write_date": "2013-10-09 08:35:07", 
    "name": "Codes(1).ods", 
    "url": "False", 
    "res_id": "44", 
    "datas": "", 
    "datas_fname": "Codes(1).ods"
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through Open ERP docs, I found out that attachments are saved as base64 encoded strings in DB unless the document addon is set up. So for anyone else who may find themselves stuck just read the data from `datas` property of the attachment resource object

```
attachment_obj = oerp.browse('ir.attachment', 17)
attachment_data = attachment_obj.datas
```